# Can't view source (code) in Netbeans 8, stuck in 'History' mode

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I am unable to view or edit the code in any Netbeans file (new or existing). I have tried 'Window' -> 'Reset Windows' which didn't change anything, anyone know of a fix? (Please click the link below to view the screenshot if my Netbeans interface)

[Screenshot of interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqMzu.png)